Как создать или есть готовый Дискорд бот для записи всего в голосовых каналов?
Идея в том что бы сделать бота или найти готового, что у меня ни как не выходит, для записи в формате mp3, сейчас будут не обязательные пожелания - что бы его можно было привязать и перепривязать к какому то гл каналу и сам бот заходил в канал как только в него зашел кто то другой и начиналась запись в идеале если бы было так, я мало что понимаю в создании ботов так что если что то пишите то либо киньте ссылку н статью либо максимально простыми словами
ну и если уж совсем то что бы он каждый раз распознавал звук или речь и только тогда начинал запись, если знаете кого то кто может это сделать то как можно с ним связаться? И договорится
просто так бы это могло быть бесплатно для всех

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Первая ссылка по запросу "бот для записи в дискорде":
https://compuals.ru/programmy-i-prilozheniya/kak-zapisat-razgovor-v-discord-s-pomoschyu-bota
Если кратко - там описан бот для записи разговоров в ДС с управлением через чат. Если этот бот не подойдет - попробуй вторую ссылку по этому же интернет запросу :)

да это единственный которого я находил, но это не совсем то надо что бы он это делал более скрытно и сам заходил в войс если там кто то есть, а так смысл теряется хоть в общем и прикольная штука

Если нужна анонимность записи и не требуется ультра качество - проще диктофон тихонько включить, когда нужно)
